# Add class to a div if a particular evaluation is true

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have data coming back.

```
declare @VALUE varchar(10) = 'MASTER';
declare @firstLetter varchar(10) = LEFT(@VALUE, 1);
select item_pk from mfr where item_pk like '%'+@firstLetter + '%'
```

[image]

I want to return only the highest one. I am trying to add something like this:

```
and MAX(RIGHT(@VALUE, 3))
```

What am I doing wrong and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your sample data, you can order it descending and get the first record

```
SELECT TOP 1 item_pk 
  FROM mfr
 WHERE item_pk LIKE '%'+@firstLetter + '%'
 ORDER BY item_pk DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you are using MAX() function on variable instead of `item_pk` and second, you are using it in WHERE clause where it doesn't belong. Just select MAX...

```
select MAX(item_pk) from mfr where item_pk like '%'+@firstLetter + '%'
```